# refresh angular material data table dataSource when button clicked

Tags: angular, datatables, angular-material, material-design, angular7

I want to refresh data-table when click on one button. There are 3 buttons.

Example: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jxh2rd) (not redirecting to customer page)

I am not getting why it's not updating the list in data-table. Data table is generic. So need to pass only data source.

Comment: alternatively, you can assign new data to `this.tableData` so MatDataSource automatically refreshed

Comment: @GaurangDhorda how to assign?

Comment: Share stackblitz of your code if possible

Comment: @GaurangDhorda Ok. I'll try to do that.

Comment: @GaurangDhorda I have created https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jxh2rd but it's not redirecting.

Comment: Answer is already accepted, in your shared `<data-table>` component you are passing values using `@input` and `@output` for changes values of data-source. You can alternatively try `rxjs subject` for better communication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expect that your custom data-table wrapper should respond to input changes then you need to handle this behavior either in ngOnChanges or using setters:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  if (changes['tableData']) {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.tableData);
    this.displayedColumns = this.columnHeader.map(c => c.columnDef);
  }
}
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-anl3fd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fshared%2Fdata-table%2Fdata-table.component.ts)**

Comment: You should also reassign those properties related to pagination

Comment: I updated stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-anl3fd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fshared%2Fdata-table%2Fdata-table.component.html

Comment: Please note I used `{ static: true }` for `ViewChild`

Comment: what happens with `{ static: true }` ?

Comment: With static true those properties(this.sort, this.paginator) will be available in NgOnChanges otherwise they will be undefined

Comment: How to do filter? I mean, have to declare that in shared component or in individual component? Filter doesn't work if I declare in individual component.

Comment: I would only pass filter object from suppliers to shared data-table component. Shared component should handle this internally, for example by using `@Input set filter(value: { [key: [string]: any }) { // your code }`

Comment: I put filter input in shared one and function in shared data-table.ts and it worked. Don't know it is good or not.

Comment: can you pls update in stackblitz? what you are telling?